# Toast Slide with Easing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a "Toast" WPF window that slides in from the bottom right corner of the screen - How can I add an 
ease to the slide that bounces back a bit

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimation
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(280),
    From = Left,
    To = Left - (Width * 2),
};
this.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, anim);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimation
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(280),
    From = Left,
    To = Left - (Width * 2),
    EasingFunction = new BounceEase()
};
```

[DoubleAnimation Class (System.Windows.Media.Animation) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Easing Functions - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can i set the distance and duration of the ease?

Comment: @user2471267 Please read the documentation that I left links to in the answer. (Apologies for the late reply; I just saw this.)